# Bayesian logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, bayesian

I need to perform a bayesian logistic regression in r. I used the 'arm' package but I don't really understand the outcome. My code:

```
M2 <- bayesglm (y ~  x1 +  x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, family=binomial(link="logit"),data=data,
    prior.scale=Inf, prior.df=Inf)
display (M2)
```

Is there a way to obtain results comparable to the classical logistic regression? Or a better way to perform bayesian logistic regression?

Comment: Not sure if this is primary a stats question or a programming-for-stats question, but you might have some luck searching on [stats.se]

Comment: I've already checked on Cross Validated but I didn't find much

Comment: Hi! You probably want to use rstanarm package